# What does "windowed streaming" stand for?

Tags: terminology, file-handling, binary, diff

So I was asking around the Mercurial development mailing list about binary diffing and patch handling and I got the following examples:

- whole file approaches (classic diff, bsdiff, Mercurial's internal
  bdiff)
- windowed streaming approaches (rsync, xdelta, libxdiff)

What does "windowed streaming" stand for in this context? (and in general)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it's an ad-hoc expression to describe the [algorithm used by rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Algorithm) which is based primarily on a [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash). It is an extremely fast way to compute diffs, but works in blocks and doesn't handle smaller changes optimally.